# How to update an XML document by stream reading a file and simultaneously stream writing output

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, stax

I have to update a node of an existing XML document, challenge is that node value can be too large (~1MB). Is there a way that node value (its stored in a separate file) can be stream read and simultaneously stream written to XML. So that at any point memory footprint is not high.

I just need to update value of one node in XML document. Original XML file is small.

Answer (score 0):

Use SAX parser instead of DOM. You can also use the StAX APIs (part of JDK package javax.xml.stream ).

Further reading-

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html
- http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html